# Database Move Resulting in Blocked IPs?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, timeout, ip, connection-timeout

I'm totally baffled by a recent problem I'm encountering.  I've moved the MySQL database of a WordPress site from one server to another.  After this, my client reports that they cannot access their site from their offices, but can access it anywhere else.

I've told them to clear cache, history, cookies, etc.  No luck.  Site just doesn't work in their office and works fine when they are anywhere else. They continue to receive timeout errors.

Site is visible to me on any browser, logged in, or logged out.

Could this be related to the database move?  Is this is an unrelated issue that just happened to coincide with this database move?

Your help would be appreciated as I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: Sounds like they've got some sort of internal DNS server that's serving the wrong IP or something.

Comment: Can they access the site in any way? Static files or anything not database related?

Comment: I should add that other members of their office can see the front end of the site.  So this can't even be IP related.  They say they've cleared their caches and cookies, so I'm left stumped as to what computer-specific issue this could possibly be.

Comment: mikevoermans, they get timeout errors, so no access at all

Comment: The database used to be on another box.  I've now shifted the data onto the same box and changed the wp-config.php to "localhost."  That's the only change I've made.

Comment: See what happens if they enter a direct URL like /blob/wp-admin/index.php. Maybe something went wonky with the redirector.

Answer (score 0):

Check the hosts files or firewalls on the PCs that can't get to the site.

If they can get to the site away from the office, check the routers at the office.

Comment: What's the easiest way to check the host files on PCs?  I can edit mine on my Mac in 3 seconds, but have no idea on a PC.

Comment: See http://coolwebdeveloper.com/2009/02/what-is-hosts-file-and-how-to-edit-hosts-file-in-win-xp-and-win-vista/

Comment: Does this solution make sense if they can access the sites while out of the office using the same machines?  They are both using laptops.

Comment: If they can get to the site away from the office, check the routers at the office or on that network.

Comment: Yikes, they work in a University, so I'm thinking that's a dead-end. But I'll try to figure out if they are indeed taking laptops home and able to access the site there.